# Passing Image from One Program to Another in JES

Tags: python, image, jython

Change the filter to purple on an image in JES

This is what I did:

```
    def pickImage():
       file = pickAFile()
       pict = makePicture(file)
       show(picture)
```

To bring in image, I entered this in command area:

```
     >>> pickImage()
```

Secondly:

```
    def antelopeSunset(image):
      for p in getPixels(image):
        value=getBlue(p)
        setBlue(p, value*0.7)
        value=getGreen(p)
        setGreen(p, value*0.7)
```

In command area, I needed to bring in photo with a purple filter:

```
     >>> image=makePicture(file)
     >>> explore(image)
     >>> antelopeSunset(image)
     >>> explore(image)
```

*My image appears with purple filter

My instructor said I did it incorrectly, saying, "The first program, pickImage(), should have called the second program and passed the picture to it.  Then it would return the filtered image to the first program for you to display." But I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is JES please?

Comment: My apologies. JES is Jython Environment for Students, using Python.